# itext7 set stamp annotation font

Tags: java, annotations, itext7

I'm converting application markups from a document management system to PDF markups.  The client application allows users select the font, size and color of stamps and text annotations.  I need to duplicate this functionality by placing circle, text, stamps and highlights on the PDF.  How would I specify the font for the text and stamp annotations?

Comment: You can create an arbitrary appearance for stamp annotations; merely if you want them to keep their appearance when edited (in particular rotated), you should take some care, cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43052760/1729265). To have the stamp use a specific font, simply create its appearance with that font.

Comment: Is there a way to approximate the logical fonts in java?

Comment: What do you mean by *logical fonts*? I'm not aware of that being a term from the pdf specification...

Comment: Basically by logical I mean the font that are including in every implementation on the java VM such as dialog, dialoginput, symbol and such.  There are substitution for theses based the OS.

Comment: Those fonts may be available for java GUIs but that has nothing to do with fonts available in pdfs.

Comment: The application that uses these fonts allows the user to markup documents of any type, i.e. word, tiff, PDF etc.  These markups are simply graphic overlays on top of the document.  We have a process for PDF documents which takes the markups and makes them a part of the PDF structure.  The fonts included in every implementation on the jvm are included in the list of fonts the user may select to create markup that I must attempt to find a substitute for when converting the application defined markups to IText/PDF objects.